# c# Active Directory Authentication User if Computer not in domain

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

How can i authenticate username and password in active directory using C# if the computer you are using not in domain?

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: I have tried the answer below and it works thanks. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried this one. The computer now i'm using is not in domain.

```
try
{
    DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer,   "IP", "Username", "Password");
    DirectoryEntry deDoc = Domain.GetDomain(context).GetDirectoryEntry();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```